# How to prove this complex integration?

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{C}f(z)\ dz=\int_0^{\pi}f(Re^{i\theta})iRe^{i\theta}\ d\theta=0$$
$f(z)$ is an analytic function,  $z=Re^{i\theta}$ & C is the semicircle in the upper half complex plane

I don't know how to proceed. Please help me prove this integral.  thanks

Comment: What properties does $f$ have?

Comment: f(z) is analytic function

Comment: That's not sufficient to lead to a $0$ value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show that the contribution from the arc of your semicircle contour vanishes as $R\to +\infty$, you can use the triangle inequality for integrals.
$$\left|\int_0^{\pi}f(Re^{i{\theta}})iRe^{i\theta}\ d\theta\right|\le\int_{0}^{\pi}\ \left|f(Re^{i\theta})\right|\left|iRe^{i\theta}\right|\ d\theta$$
but note that $f$ has to decay faster than $1/z$, i.e.,
there exists $M>0$ and $a>1$ such that,
$$\left|f(z)\right|<\frac{M}{|z|^a}$$
then,
$$\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{M}{|Re^{i\theta}|}iRe^{i\theta}\ d\theta\right|&\le\int_0^{\pi}\left|\frac{M}{|Re^{i\theta}|^a}\right|\left|iRe^{i\theta}\right|\ d\theta \\
&\le\int_0^{\pi}\frac{M}{R^a}R\ d\theta \\
&\le\frac{M\pi}{R^{a-1}}
\end{align*}$$
which goes to $0$ as $R\to+\infty$.